# Facebook PHP SDK returning user ID even after logout

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I'm using the FB PHP SDK to log users in. Nothing fancy here - just calling `$fb->getLoginUrl()` to generate the login link, user goes through to it, authorises, is bounced back to my site and they're logged in. So far, so good.

On a page reserveed for logged-in users I have this code:

```
echo $fb->getUser(); //supposedly outputs user ID or 0 on failure
```

But the thing is it outputs the user ID **even if I've gone to Facebook manually and logged out of it**. It never seems to output `0` for me, i.e. detects that I'm logged out.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to detect login status?

(Note: the JS SDK is not an option for me)

Comment: since you're not using the JS SDK, it may take a little bit till the server side notice that you're no longer logged in.

Comment: Hmm, not sure because I just tried it again, some two hours after logging out of FB, and it's still returning my user ID!

Comment: And the access token when will expire? It seems that somehow the cookie of your app as your information persisted.Try going to your facebook profile and remove the permissions for your app/website, lougout and then try again checking if it still returns the fb_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the destroySession method and also kill the session variable when you want to logout.

```
include('fb-php-sdk/facebook.php');
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '641xxxx559';
$config['secret'] = '3bxxxxxxcd1c';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act'] == "logout") {
    $facebook->destroySession();

            // destroy session var here. Should be in format of "fmb_$appID"
}


$user = $facebook->getUser();
echo $user;
if ($user) {

    try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
    $user = null;
    }
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($user_profile);
    echo "</pre>";  
    $logout = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();

    //echo $logout;

    echo "<a href='test.php?act=logout'>Logout</a>";


} else {

    $login = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"email","display"=>"popup","redirect_uri"=>"http://domain.com/test.php"));

    echo "<a href='".$login."'>Login</a>";

}
```

As you can see I am passing the scope key in the params array to request what I want back.  The first time this is run the user will be asked by facebook to confirm what ever is being asked for in the scope.